# visual change notification event?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Anybody that happens to know how to do this would really be helping me out.

Maybe its simple, I don't know, but it involves embedded SWF's so I imagine it could entail interacting with event handlers or methods in an embedded SWF.

But anyway, here it is:

I have several embedded SWF's on a canvas (in SWFLoaders) and when one of them changes visually I need to know which one changed.

The 'render'  event provides only part of the solution:

If an SWFLoader contains a videodisplay there are continual render events generated in the parent app while that videodisplay is running. If the SWFLoader just contains some static input control otoh, there are no render messages in the parent app until someone interacts with that control and changes it visually, and then there are render events broadcast in the parent app.  So, this is clearly part of what my requirements are.

The problem with the render event however, is that it does *not* tell you *which* embedded SWF actually changed (in the target or currentTarget.)

But I need to know which one changed.

(Are there seperate render messages being generated *within* an embedded app (seperate from those in the parent app) for example, that could be detected.)

Comment: is the changing of the render state the only thing that is going to be able to tell you which is active? or is the change of render always activated by a user interaction?

Comment: The render event is the only thing i know about that even roughly approximates what I need. But as I said it doesn't tell which embedded item changed which is what I need, it only detects that it changed. But its not fired by user interaction as such, but by visual change to a control.  I think actually its caused by controls calling stage.invalidate().  But anyway, I came up with a solution which will work for me so I'll just post it as an answer below  and close this, because no one even knows what I'm talking about evidently.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is as follows:

When a render event occurs, I check if there is a visible swfloader within the browser window, and then I do a BitmapData.draw of its contents to a bitmapdata which is saved.  With each new render event, I compare 10% of the pixels of the saved bitmap to the new bitmap and that will tell me whether or not the embedded .swf visual content has actually changed.  a 10% sample has proven to be more than sufficient (just iterating through the vectors of the respective bitmaps with the vector index incrementing by 10, instead of 1.)

---

BitmapData.draw is plenty fast and iterating through 10000 vector elements is like a millisecond.

Comment: This is probably the best answer.

Comment: Well, its interesing you would say it was "the best".  I was thinking it was "good enough" and of the saying, "The best is enemy of the good enough."  I had tunnel vision for a couple of days unfortunately about how I wanted to do this so was unable to see other solutions.

Comment: It might be faster to draw the second bitmapdata over the first one with a difference blend mode, then do a getColorBounds to see if any pixels are not black.

Comment: It sounds like it would be faster.  I'll check into that and get back to you.  Incidentally, I found that for some controls the BitmapData.draw method is quite a bit slower than the norm, for example a RichTextEditor example in the flex-sdk is much slower than for any of the other example controls.  My point being - to return to my original post - I really do need something in the flash player to tell me if an embedded SWF has changed visually.

Comment: It sounds like it would be faster.  I'll check into that and get back to you.  Incidentally, I found that for some controls the BitmapData.draw method is quite a bit slower than the norm, for example a RichTextEditor example in the flex-sdk is much slower than for any of the other example controls.  My point being - to return to my original post - I really do need something in the flash player to tell me if an embedded SWF has changed visually.

Comment: sharvey, its not doing what I expected:

var bmd_s2:BitmapData = bmd_s.clone();
bmd_s2.draw(bmd_img[n],null,null,"difference");   
Dumper.info(
  bmd_s2.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF,0,false).toString());
   
if (!bmd_img[n].compare(bmd_s)) {
  Dumper.info("the same"); return;
}  

Here's the ouput
[INFO]: (x=77, y=34, w=289, h=147) (String)
[INFO]: the same (String)

so they're the same but GetColorBoundsRect is returning a large rectangle.  (Probably missing something.)

(BTW BitmapData.compare is not all that fast -that's why I'm not using it.)